# failed to connect Acer AS 4736ZG to TV through HDMI

Tags: laptop, hdmi, tv

It's my sister's laptop and I just got a new HDMI cable for her.

After she connected the laptop to her LCD TV, she found out that pressing Fn+F5 doens't work at all, both TV and laptop screen didn't change at all.

There are two HDMI port on her TV and she has tried to switch the input between them, that doesn't work also.

So, is there any way to help this situation? My sister doens't live in the city with me, so I can only help her through the internet. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated:)

ps. the OS is windows xp.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, the problem has been solved: my sister didn't press Fn+F5 correctly...The right way should be to keep Fn pressed down and then click F5 to switch.

Also, if the LaunchManger utility from ACER has been installed on her laptop, it would be easier to find out the reason.